# How to Check if profile exists in firebase with ionic?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to ionic and firebase, currently I'm working on a project, and I'm trying to make my app redirect the user to the profile creation page if he doesn't have a profile registered on firebase. This is what I currently have in firebase:

[image]

And this is the login-view code:

```
export class LoginPage {
userModel: UserModel;
splash = true;
constructor(
  private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
  private afDatabase:AngularFireDatabase,
  public navCtrl: NavController,
  public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
  public alertCtrl: AlertController,
  public authService: AuthService,
  public navParams: NavParams) {
  this.userModel = new UserModel();
}

signIn() {
  let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: 'Iniciando sesión. Por favor, espere...'
  });
  loading.present();

  this.authService.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.userModel).then(result => 
  {
      loading.dismiss();
      console.log(result.uid);

      //take the user to the Homepage if he has a profile
      //otherwise take him to ProfileCreation

      this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
  }).catch(error => {
      loading.dismiss();

      console.log(error);
      this.alert('Error', 'Ha ocurrido un error inesperado. Por favor intente nuevamente.');
  });
 }
```

I've been doing some research and found some functions like exists() and hasChild() but none has worked for me.

I'd apreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the same problem doing some like this.

```
 import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';

 createProfile: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>

 this.createProfile=this.database.object(`Usuarios/${data.uid}`,{ preserveSnapshot: true });    
 this.createProfile.take(1).subscribe(snapshot=>{
    if(snapshot.val() == null ){
       this.navCtrl.setRoot('InfoProfilePage');
    }else{
       this.navCtrl.setRoot('TabsPage');
    }
 });
```